# What sites provide public web font libraries to link to?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

Are there any sites except google that provide a library that one can link directly to in your css file?

Like google-webfonts @font-face so that they're hosting, and no local files for you.

```
{
    font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/font?kit=YDAoL...JF4')
         format('truetype');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is Typekit ( http://typekit.com/ ), but it isn't free.

Comment: That's the one and only, anyone? Might be worth $49.99per year

Comment: Typekit is probably the biggest one that does specifically what you need. On reflection, Fontdeck is also reasonably well-known but it doesn't have the same penetration that Typekit does for whatever reason(perhaps because it's still kind of new).

Answer (score 1):

If you're after Japanese fonts, M+ fonts allow hot-linking and have instructions on how to do so on their site:

http://mplus-fonts.sourceforge.jp/webfonts/index-en.html

The license is open & free:

> Unlimited permission is granted to
>   use, copy, and distribute it, with or
>   without modification, either
>   commercially and noncommercially

You didn't specify a particular language - and these fonts do have english characters in their font sets as well.

Answer (score 0):

I use this one

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface

Comment: but they don't host it for you, right. You'll have to download the fontface package and serve it locally?

Comment: Yes, same with cufon (which isn't a font-embedding service, anyway - it works by generating image replacements).

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a fairly large number of services like Typekit, just less well-know. However, like Typekit, almost all of them are paid services that require a monthly charge to use.

Smashing Magazine recently published a list of these services, which you can see here: [**Review of Popular Web Font Embedding Services**](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/20/review-of-popular-web-font-embedding-services/)

Answer (score 0):

How about [google web font](https://www.google.com/fonts)?

[Here's](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started?hl=en) the tutorial on how to apply it.

And here's an example of it.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Tangerine', serif;
        font-size: 48px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Making the Web Beautiful!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```